# Push new widget to DOJO attach point not replace

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have the following

```
    postCreate: function() {
        this.items.forEach(lang.hitch(this, function(item) {
            new SideNavigationItem({
                name: item.name
            }, this.container);
        }));
    }
```

Which adds a new `li` item to a `ul`, the `ul` template has an attach point that I want to built all of the `li`s into - however doing the above just replaces the attach point's content with the next `li` being created upon iteration

Any ideas how I can go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead.  The key is to use _WidgetBase placeAt() method which functions similar to domConstruct place() method

```
Example
// place a new button as the first element of some div
var button = new Button({ label:"click" }).placeAt("wrapper","first");
```

If you omit the third parameter, like I did in the solution below, the default position is 'last' which is what you want.

Template

```
<ul data-dojo-attach-point="myAttachPoint" >
    <li>existing list item</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
    this.items.forEach(lang.hitch(this, function(item) {

         var listItem = new SideNavigationItem({name: item.name});
         listItem.placeAt(this.myAttachPoint);

         //if that doesn't work try it just with plain <li> item
         //var listItem = domConstruct.toDom("<li></li>");
         //domConstruct.place(listItem, this.myAttachPoint);
    }));
```